# How to add new API extension to the Chromium project?

Tags: javascript, c++, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

I'm customizing Chromium browser for specific internal protocol. For now I have JavaScript extension that communicates with server. I need also to change Chromium behavior. So, I decided to add custom API extension. I'll use in it JS extension as `chrome.xxx.setUserConfig(someInteger)`. Now I need to create this xxx extension in C++ Chromium internals. I used information from [https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/creating-new-apis] documentation, but without success. I did something wrong, but I don't understand what exactly.

*UPD: At the end I got the success. Here I describe my steps, and for now they look to be correct.*

I did steps listed below:

1. API description

1.1. I added `extensions/common/api/xxx.json:`

```
[
  {
    "namespace": "xxx",
    "description": "xxx",
    "functions": [
      {
        "name": "setUserConfig",
        "type": "function",
        "description": "xxx",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "someVar",
            "type": "integer",
            "minimum": 15,
            "description": "xxx"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

1.2. In `extensions/common/api/schema.gni` I added:

```
extensions_api_schema_files_ = [
...
  "xxx.json",
...
]
```

1.3. In `extensions/common/api/_api_features.json` I added:

```
{
...
  "xxx": {
    "dependencies": [ "permission:xxx" ],
    "contexts": [ "blessed_extension" ]
  },
...
}
```

1.4. In `extensions/common/api/_permission_features.json` I added:

```
...
  "xxx": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "extension_types": [ "extension", "legacy_packaged_app", "platform_app" ]
  },
...
```

2. Build instructions

2.1. I added `extensions/browser/api/xxx/BUILD.gn`:

```
import("//extensions/buildflags/buildflags.gni")
assert(enable_extensions, Cannot depend on extensions because enable_extensions=false.")

source_set("xxx"){
  sources = [
    "xxx_api.cc",
    "xxx_api.h",
  ]

  deps = [
    "//build:chromeos_buildflags",
    "//components/keyed_service/content",
    "//content/public/browser",
    "//extensions/common",
    "//extensions/common/api",
  ]

  public_deps = [ "//extensions/browser:browser_sources" ]

}
```

2.2. I added in `extensions/browser/api/BUILD.gn`:

```
group("api_implementations") {
  public_deps = [
...
   "//extensions/browser/api/xxx",
...
  ]
```

3. Chromium internal entities

3.1. I added to `extensions/browser/extension_function_histogram_value.h` :

```
enum HistogramValue {
...
  XXX_SETUSERCONFIG = 1556,
  // Last entry: Add new entries above, then run:
  // python tools/metrics/histograms/update_extension_histograms.py
  ENUM_BOUNDARY
};
```

`1556` I added as the biggest value in the list

3.2. I added to `extensions/common/mojom/api_permission_id.mojom`:

```
enum APIPermissionID {
...
  kXxx = 231

  // Add new entries at the end of the enum and be sure to update the
  // "ExtensionPermission3" enum in tools/metrics/histograms/enums.xml
  // (by running update_extension_permission.py).
};
```

`231` I added as the biggest value in the list

3.3. I added to `extensions/common/permissions/extensions_api_permissions.cc`:

```
constexpr APIPermissionInfo::InitInfo permissions_to_register[] = {
...
    {APIPermissionID::kXxx, "xxx"},
...
};
```

4. Extension interface

4.1. I added `extensions/browser/api/xxx/xxx_api.h`:

```
#ifndef EXTENSIONS_API_XXX_API_H_
#define EXTENSIONS_API_XXX_API_H_

#include "extensions/browser/extension_function.h"

namespace extensions {

class XxxSetUserConfigFunction : public ExtensionFunction {
 public:
  DECLARE_EXTENSION_FUNCTION("xxx.setUserConfig", XXX_SETUSERCONFIG)

 protected:
  ~XxxSetUserConfigFunction() override;

  // ExtensionFunction:
  ResponseAction Run() override;
};

}  // namespace extensions

}  // namespace extensions

#endif  // EXTENSIONS_BROWSER_API_XXX_API_H_
```

4.2. I added `extensions/browser/api/xxx/xxx_api.cc`:

```
#include "extensions/browser/api/xxx/xxx_api.h"

namespace extensions {

XxxSetUserConfigFunction::~XxxSetUserConfigFunction() = default;

ExtensionFunction::ResponseAction XxxSetUserConfigFunction::Run() {
  int someInt = 0;
  EXTENSION_FUNCTION_VALIDATE(args_->GetInteger(0, &someInt));

  return RespondNow(NoArguments());
}

}  // namespace extensions
```

Like this now I hope to use this API in my extensions: `manifest.json`

```
{
...
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        "xxx",
...
    ]
}
```

And somewhere in the script: `chrome.xxx.setUserConfig(20);`.

I build Chromium:

```
python tools/metrics/histograms/update_extension_histograms.py
python tools/metrics/histograms/update_extension_permission.py
gn gen out/Default
autoninja -C out\Default chrome
```

Build was successful. As the scripts execution results tools/metrics/histograms/enums.xml was changed.

P. S. I'm working under Windows 10. Chromium Version 93.0.4544.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit) is used.

Answer (score 0):

After describing this question I repeated steps and made some Chromium debug researches and got the success. I've decided to describe correct steps in the question. So, feel free to repeat it.
`xxx.json` describes some initial interface with some integer variable and some limit. This is starting point for the real API description.